# Issue with ion-Slides swipe

Tags: ionic2

I want to disable swipes on my ion-slides.

home.html

```
  <ion-slides>   
    <ion-slide>
       <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
       <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
       <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-slide> 
  </ion-slides>
```

home.ts

```
...

@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

....

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  this.slides.lockSwipes(true);

  }
...
```

But this gives a lot of errors..can anyone tell what may be the issue?

ERRORS:

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'lockSwipes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'lockSwipes' of undefined
at new QuestionDetails...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the constructor is executed, the DOM has not been rendered yet (so the instance of the slider doesn't exist yet). Use `ionViewDidEnter` instead

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.slides.lockSwipes(true);
}
```